# Spring-data query method ignores parameter of type Class

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am using spring-data-jpa 2.0.7.RELEASE, spring-core 5.0.6.RELEASE, hibernate 5.2.17.Final, and java 8.

I have a repository class with a query method that takes a parameter of type Class. For example:

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends Repository<MyEntity, Integer>{

    @Query("select m from MyEntity m "
            + "where TYPE(m) = :myEntityClass "
            + "and m.attribute1 = :attribute1 ")
    List<MyEntityClass> findByClassAndAttribute1(
            @Param("myEntityClass") Class<? extends MyEntity> myEntityClass, 
            @Param("attribute1") boolean attribute1);
}
```

`MyEntity` is an abstract class with three subclasses, and it is mapped with `@Inheritance` and `@DiscriminatorColumn`.

The problem is that spring-data does not set `myEntityClass` parameter in the Hibernate query, but it does set the boolean `attribute1` parameter.

Here is the error message I get from hibernate:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter [myEntityClass] not set
```

As a test, I removed the `myEntityClass` parameter and the query runs without errors. Besides, the same query method used to work with spring-data-jpa 1.9.5.RELEASE.

Why is the `myEntityClass` parameter not set? Is it a spring-data bug?

Thank you for your help.